# Multiple jQuery versions overwriting asynchronously in gmail chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Basically, I have a gmail chrome extension that injects a specific version of jQuery into the main page (This works fine) and then adds some jQuery plugins to it that the extension will use later on as needed.

The problem is that because all jQuery versions (As far as I know) use the $ to call functions (And plugins), if another extension comes in and loads its version of jQuery over the top of mine, then I lose my installed plugins. Sometimes, I have even seen the version used by the other extension being so old that some of the "standard" jQuery functions I use are not in it and they come up as undefined also.

Is there any easy way to separate out my versions from any and all other extensions that may be playing in the gmail box alongside mine? I have no way of knowing which extensions my users might be installing, so I Cannot just account for everything this way. There are tons of gmail chrome extensions these days and "playing nice" seems to be a huge issue that is become more problematic over time.

Any ideas how to "protect" my jQuery version and plugins?

Comment: How are you injecting jQuery into the tab? content_scripts are sandboxed in different contexts so different extensions code can't interact with each others.

Comment: var q = document.createElement('script');
    q.src = document.getElementById("extensionPath").innerHTML+'js/jquery.js';
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(q);

Comment: The above was injected from within a script that was injected from within a content script in the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Abraham stated in the comments in my original question, the right thing to do here was to place the extension javascript files inside content scripts so that they were in an "isolated world" that couldn't be modified by other extensions or the page itself. You can even use this as a way to include several JS files (In my case such as jquery and angular as well as several jquery plugins) explicitly without having to define them all in a single file, and have them still isolated from the page itself.

Just be careful about the order you define them in the manifest file since this is exactly the order that chrome will load them (Since some may be dependencies of others).

`Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page. It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse: JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any variables defined by content scripts.`

To reference the Google documentation on this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can save your jQuery object in a specific variable and reference this variables in your plugins:

```
// load jQuery and any plugins here
<script src="BryanPjQuery.js"></script>
<script src="plugins.js"></script>
<script>
var BryanPjQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {

   // add all code here. $ refers to BryanPjQuery
   // so within this function $ = jQuery, outside this function
   // other versions of $ can be used

  });
})(BryanPjQuery);
</script>
```

For more details see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ or (with more examples) https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: While I think this should generally work, I failed to mention that I am using angularJS in a separately injected file which interacts with the DOM. I am not sure I can wrap all of my angular code inside this variable in this way. Does this change things?

Comment: Mmh. I don't know. I just did some testing and got mixed results depending on the plugin.

Comment: I generally think this is a good idea and worth exploring. I'll need to do some specific testing around it to see if I can get it all to work together (I have a lot of stuff going on in my app). Thank you for the idea as this may end up being a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just include jquery in the Manifest but don't include them in the web accessible resources part of the list.  This seems to work OK for me.  This way only content scripts can still access jQuery and it won't override anything or vice-a-versa.

- Include jQuery here:  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts
- DONT include jQuery with the web accessible resources section. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources